# Hook or filter for navigation menus

Tags: php, wordpress

Is here a hook or a filter for when a new navigation menu is created from admin panel, I would like to bind a action when that happens. I cant seam to find one?

Comment: Maybe wp_update_nav_menu ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked, in this hook

```
 //hooks triggers on any term create
 add_action( 'create_term', some_function, 10, 3 );
```

passes 3 values $term_id, $term_taxonomy_id, $taxonomy,

after that I checked if the taxonomy is 'nav_menu'